# Rails production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails project when I started it in production mode I have all.css and all.js files. And when I restarting they stays. How I can see changes in production mode (when css files or js files have changed)? Maybe I need to delete them, but do it everytime by hands... not cool. Maybe somebody have some kind of elegant solution? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The point of the production environment is that your assets shouldn't change all that much. That way, your browser can cache them and load them faster. If you need to check asset changes often, you should switch to the development environment.

Otherwise, you can run `rake assets:clean` then `rake assets:precompile` to make sure they update properly. And don't forget to clear your browser cache.